# Laravel not seeing user as logged in until after page load

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

When a user logs in on my site, they are redirected back to the homepage but they are shown a guest view of the page, when they should be logged in. This testing snippet that I added shows that the user is not seen as logged in when the page is loaded.

```html
@auth
    <p>{{ Auth::user()->email }}</p>
@else
    <p>not logged in</p>
@endauth
```

I wrote an endpoint that I gets hit after the page load to check if the user is logged in

```html
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        checkIfLoggedIn();
    });

    function checkIfLoggedIn() {
        axios.get('auth-check').
            then(({data}) => {
                    console.log(data);
            })
    }
</script>
```

```html
public function checkAuth() {
    return json_encode(Auth::user());
}
```

And hitting this endpoint successfully returns the laravel user data of the logged in account. Does anyone have ideas on why the initial page load isn't seeing the user as logged in?

Comment: What is the value of "same_site" attribute in "config/session.php"?

Comment: Seems like it should be `@auth` and `@guest` (not `@else`) based on the docs, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @RaviPatel its set to 'strict'

Comment: @Jesse it still isn't seeing the user as logged in with `@guest` instead of `@else`

Comment: @M.Heck Try setting "same_site" attribute to "Lax" to see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: @RaviPatel that fixed the issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The fix for the issue was to set "same_site" to "lax" in session.php.